# Laravel 6 API doesn't write error 500 in logs

Tags: laravel, api, error-handling, axios, http-status-code-500

How to set Laravel to catch/log 500 errors from API?

I have Laravel 6.x and, in .env, I have `APP_ENV=production` with `APP_DEBUG=false` and a function with `DB::table('table_doesnt_exists')->get()`.

If I access a web route from browser which call that function I see on the screen "500 Server Error" and the error is written in logs, which is perfect.

If use `axios` and call an API route which call the same function I only get HTTP response 500, without any response, and most important there is no error in logs.

Comment: is the api in the same environment?

Comment: is the same laravel(the same project)... and this happens on both local server (homestead) and also on a vps.

Comment: try to clear the config cache. And check the log file permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manage to make it works after trying multiple combinations.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=false
```

The error is written in logs and the API only return

```
{ message: "Server Error" }
```